# Finding the kth to the last element of a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I was trying to implement this recursively, but I'm not sure why this code doesn't work (this is assuming that I have a length function that returns correctly):

```
Node findk(Node head, int k) {
    if (node_length(head)==k) {
        return head; }
    else {
        return findk(head.next, k-1);}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you need to return ? Position of K'th element ?

Comment: Are you spinning off into infinite recursion? What happens when head.next is null? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work ? Are you trying to find the K'th element from the start or the end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- you should not be decrementing `k` as you go down the list, and
- you should pay attention to hitting `null` before reaching `k`-th element when the list is too short.

Here is one possible fix:

```
Node findk(Node head, int k) {
    if (head == null) return null;
    if (node_length(head)==k) return head;
    return findk(head.next, k);
}
```

Note that this solution is O(n<sup>2</sup>), because `node_length`, which must be O(1), is called for each of `N-k` nodes of the list. There are several ways of doing it faster - for example, by finding `int m = node_length(head)`, and then returning `(m-k)`-th node from the beginning of the list.

Comment: Are there any issues that might occur on the stack? I was reading Cracking the Coding interview, and the author says that we can't "pass back nodes through the stack" for answering this question recursively

Comment: @honeysingh The biggest stack-related issue here would be overflowing the stack when the list is too long. However, it would not be an issue if the compiler performs tail call optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the K'th element from the end You are decrementing the value of K which is wrong, the correct code is as below :

```
Node findk(Node head, int k) {
  if (node_length(head)==k) {
    return head; 
  } else {
    return findk(head.next, k);
  }
}
```

Also I hope your node_length() method takes care of the scenario where the Node passed to it is null.